# Reverse array, and return the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have to write a function that reverses the array (i know about the reverse method, but this time i have to write a function). This function has to take array variable as input and return the SAME variable but with reversed order of elements. What i fail to understand is why this code works :

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
    array.shift(array.push(i));
  }
  return array;
};
```

And this code doesnt

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
    array.unshift(array.pop(i));
  }
  return array;
};
```

While they are doing absolutely same thing?

Comment: By definition they're not doing the same thing. `shift` and `unshift` are different methods.

Comment: The first one doesn't "work" if the goal is to reverse the contents of the array it receives. Instead, what it does is *replace* its contents with the numbers `1` through the length of the array in reverse, obliterating its original contents. E.g., `["a", "b", "c"]` becomes `[3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: `.push` method returns the current `length` of the array!

Comment: If you push shifted elements you'll just get the same array. Same thing if you unshift a popped element.

Comment: I don't think your first version of code works. Are you just happened to have reverse a [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: What is the point of providing a code snippet which doesn't display anything?

Comment: Try walking through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On the second version of your code

First, note that the `pop` method takes no argument, so passing it *i* has no additional effect.

Then take an example of an array you might pass to this function:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

In each iteration you pop the last element from the array and shift it back in at the front with this statement (I removed the *i*):

```
 array.unshift(array.pop());
```

This is what happens in the 4 iterations of your loop:

```
 ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
 ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
 ['b', 'd', 'a', 'b']
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

... and your back with the same array you started with.

#### On the first version of your code

Note that `shift` and `push` seem to be in the wrong order to be in any way useful. Also, `push` takes the argument as the value to add at the end of the array, but you are passing it an index, not a value from the array:

```
array.shift(array.push(i));
```

The shift then takes the first element out, and its value is ... lost.

So this is what happens in the iterations:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 4]
['c', 'd', 4, 3]
['d', 4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

So, this also does not reverse your array (only if you happened to pass it `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but as you can see that would be pure accidental).

If you would have swapped the `shift` and `push` like this:

```
array.push(array.shift());
```

The code would have made a bit more sense, as you would actually take out the first value from the array and add it back in at the end. But just like the second version of the code, you would end up with the original array then. You would just have cycled the elements around without changing their order.

#### How to reverse

You could swap the values starting from the two far ends of your array, and work inwards. I will use here the ES6 destructuring assignment syntax for making the swap:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1, j = 0; i > j; i--, j++) {
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}
// Demo:
var array = ['a','b','c','d'];
reverseArrayInPlace(array);
console.log(array); // ['d','c','b','a']
```